# Trying airflow on databricks, but dag is stuck on "running"

Tags: airflow, databricks

I am following this guide for setting up Airflow on Databricks:
https://docs.databricks.com/en/workflows/jobs/how-to/use-airflow-with-jobs.html

This is my python code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.databricks.operators.databricks import DatabricksRunNowOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
  'owner': 'airflow'
}

with DAG('databricks_dag',
  start_date = days_ago(2),
  schedule_interval = None,
  default_args = default_args
  ) as dag:

  opr_run_now = DatabricksRunNowOperator(
    task_id = 'run_now',
    databricks_conn_id = 'databricks_default',
    job_id = 123 #not my actual job ID
  )
```

When I trigger the DAG via the Airflow UI, I see that it's stuck on Running.
I setup my conn_id and I am using a PAT token.

I have both the webserver and the scheduler up and running, and any sample DAG's get executed successfully.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxQrx.png

Comment: In Databricks can you see the job run started? Has it finished?

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy the job run does not start.